# Can't create an app ID on "developer enterprise program" if the same app ID was created in "developer program"

Tags: ios, certificate, enterprise, app-id

I have 2 ios dev programs, one "developer program" and one "developer enterprise program".
When I go on the certificates portal (safari), I create an appId xx.yy.com on the "developer program". Then I try to create this same appId xx.yy.com on the "developer enterprise program", and it fails with a popup :

> There were errors in the data supplied. Please correct and re-submit.
>   An App ID with Identifier 'testjp.furetcompany.com' is not available.
>   Please enter a different string.

So does it mean I have to create a new appId for distributing my app in house ?
If so that means create 2 targets on Xcode, one for appstore distribution, and one for enterprise distribution ?

Comment: yes you need to create two identifiers (App ID) for dev and enterprise. Create two targets is of your choice(You also can change identifiers when you distribute).

Comment: Oh OK. Creating 2 targets is a bit overkill so I'll opt for what you suggest. Would be better if that could be automatic. Thx very much.

Comment: you are welcome